# how to get list of class names from reference class in R

Tags: r, reference-class

I have this code:

```
private$svg <- if(is(private$idaPlotObj, "DivosGridBmiPlot")){
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

in my code and I'm trying to refactor this code and get list of classes from private$idaPlotObj that is reference class, but all I get is this:

```
[1] "BMIDynamicRatiosPlot"
attr(,"package")
[1] "divosBMI"
```

when I'm using `attr(private$idaPlotObj,"class")` or `class(private$idaPlotObj)`

How can I get all class names from reference class? If I will have 4 classes I will need to check each one with `is`. I would like to compare vectors to test if class is on the list.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Reference classes, therefore a bit a shot in the dark: could you use `myclass <- class(private$idaPlotObj)` to get the class of your object and then use `class_info <- getRefClass(myclass); class_info@generator$def@refSuperClasses` to get the vector of all class names?

Comment: @starja it works. thanks. You can add this as an answer it looks simpler than the answer that was already added.

Comment: Done; I think the other answer is a nice one-step solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you could do for reference classes:

```
 object@.xData$.refClassDef@refSuperClasses
```

Example:

```
setRefClass("Polygon", fields = list(sides="integer"))
setRefClass("Regular")
setRefClass("Triangle", contains = "Polygon")
EQL = setRefClass("EquilateralTriangle", contains = c("Triangle", "Regular"))

tri1 <- EQL$new(sides=3L)
```

Now to obtain all the classes of `tri1` we do:

```
tri1@.xData$.refClassDef@refSuperClasses
[1] "Triangle"    "Regular"     "Polygon"     "envRefClass"
```

### Edit

Putting everything together, you could do:

```
getRefClassNames <- function(obj) {
   c(class(obj), head(obj@.xData$.refClassDef@refSuperClasses, -1))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that splits it up into several steps:

1. get the current class name of the object:

```
myclass <- class(private$idaPlotObj)
```

2. use `getRefClass` to get the information about the associated classes:

```
class_info <- getRefClass(myclass)
```

3. you get an object back where the info is a bit hidden, so you have to extract it:

```
class_info@generator$def@refSuperClasses
```